# Regex to match exactly one comma separeted strings

Tags: python, regex

Example:

```
src: anyword, anyword, anyword
```

I want to check if `src` contains only `one comma` separated strings like given in example

I wrote `(.[^\s*]+,.*[^,\s*]+$)` this but it's failing with some scenarios

For me, following scenarios are **not valid**

```
src: abc, ,1232
src: ,abc, dasf
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/UyQ5KX/1

Comment: All lines start with src?

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/P4XGyH/1 `^source: [^\s,]+,[^,\s]+$`

Comment: `: *[^\s,]+(?:, *[^,\s]+)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JAX4M5/1)) or `source: *[^\s,]+(?:, *[^,\s]+)*$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/JAX4M5/2))?

Comment: I think you need to define exactly what you mean by "string". A single space **is** a string, yet you consider it invalid (your first example).. What about words like "O'Hara" or "Mason-Dickson", or "3rd", are those valid strings or not?

Comment: @Thefourthbird its not allowing space between words

Comment: @Błotosmętek for me string is any word apart from space. Yes '3rd', 'O'Hara' are valid one

Comment: @Shri You could add optional spaces or whitespace chars around the comma `^source: [^\s,]+\s*,\s*[^,\s]+$` https://regex101.com/r/g4vqCc/1

Comment: @DaniMesejo `src` is just example. case is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
: *[^\s,]+(?:, *[^,\s]+)*$
```

Or, to allow more whitespaces than just space between words:

```
:[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*[^\s,]+(?:,[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*[^,\s]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JAX4M5/1)

If there must be 1+ non-colon chars from the start of string till the colon, you may add `^[^:]+` before the patterns above.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]+`  - 1+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*` - 0 or more occurrences of only horizontal whitespaces
- `[^\s,]+` - 1 or more occurrences of characters other than whitespace and comma
- `(?:,[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*[^,\s]+)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `[^\S\n\v\f\r\u2028\u2029]*` - 0 or more occurrences of only horizontal 
    whitespaces
  - `[^\s,]+` - 1 or more occurrences of characters other than whitespace and comma
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I replaced `*` with `+` for one or more time and it worked for me. `*[^\s,]+(?:, *[^,\s]+)*$` Thanks